# Error: Found item Drawable/string more than one time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I get the following error when tring to build:
\src\main\res\values\drawables.xml: Error: Found item Drawable/ic_btn_round_minus more than one time
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Using:

- Android Studio v3.0.1
- gradle v2.2
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion 23.0.1

Code:

```
<drawable name="ic_btn_round_minus">res/drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_btn_round_minus.png</drawable>
<drawable name="ic_btn_round_minus">res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_btn_round_minus.png</drawable>
<drawable name="ic_btn_round_minus">res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_btn_round_minus.png</drawable>
```

I found a similar issue at: [Google issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36974524)

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Added code. Edited OP.

Comment: go to the url in that error and remove all the drawables named *ic_btn_round_minus.png* except one

Comment: Ok, but in this case the different resolutions will be not handled, right?

Comment: can you show the full code of *\src\main\res\values\drawables.xml* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for maintaining different resolutions on your apk, you can maintain different drawable folders(eg. drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi) on your *\src\main\res* folder and keep different resolution of same drawable on respective folders. no need to mention them in *\values\drawables.xml*

Comment: It was enough to delete them from  \values\drawables.xml. Thanks for your help!